# read from csv to object[] C#

Tags: c#, linq, csv

I am trying to read from a .csv file to an object array.

There are other solutions here that give solutions for lists but I cannot seem to make it work for me.

Object definition:

```
public class DTOClass
{
    //declare data members
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string stock_symbol { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public double stock_price_open { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public double stock_price_close { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public double stock_price_low { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public double stock_price_high { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public double stock_price_adj_close { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public long stock_volume { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string stock_exchange { get; set; }
}
```

Instance declaration:

```
private DTOClass[] _dTOs;
```

Filter method:

```
private List<DTOClass> FromCsv(string csvLine, List<DTOClass> rest)
{
    DataTable _dt = new DataTable();

    string[] values = csvLine.Split(',');

    int j = _dt.Rows.Count;
    for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
    {
        DTOClass dto = new DTOClass();

        dto.Date = Convert.ToDateTime(values[0]);
        dto.stock_symbol = Convert.ToString(values[1]);
        dto.stock_price_open = Convert.ToDouble(values[2]);
        dto.stock_price_close = Convert.ToDouble(values[3]);
        dto.stock_price_low = Convert.ToDouble(values[4]);
        dto.stock_price_high = Convert.ToDouble(values[5]);
        dto.stock_price_adj_close = Convert.ToDouble(values[6]);
        dto.stock_volume = Convert.ToInt64(values[7]);
        dto.stock_exchange = Convert.ToString(values[8]);

        rest.Add(dto);
    }

    return rest;
}
```

Calling filter:

```
DTO = File.OpenText(Filename).ReadLine().Select(v => FromCsv(v.ToString(), 
_restDto)).ToArray();
```

I need this to return to an object array because it then goes into a CollectionView on a datagrid.

But I keep getting this error:

"Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List[]' to 'MBM.Services.DTOClass[]'"

I know that I'm obviously returning a list of a list, but I've tried other methods that are offered and I'm simply stumped.

I've also tried this:

```
private static DataTable GetDataTableFromCSVFile(string csv_file_path)
{
    DataTable csvData = new DataTable();

    try
    {
        using (TextFieldParser csvReader = new TextFieldParser(csv_file_path))
        {
            csvReader.SetDelimiters(new string[] { "," });
            //csvReader.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
            string[] colFields = csvReader.ReadFields();

            foreach (string column in colFields)
            {
                DataColumn datecolumn = new DataColumn(column);
                datecolumn.AllowDBNull = true;
                csvData.Columns.Add(datecolumn);
            }

            while (!csvReader.EndOfData)
            {
                string[] fieldData = csvReader.ReadFields();
                //Making empty value as null
                for (int i = 0; i < fieldData.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (fieldData[i] == "")
                    {
                        fieldData[i] = null;
                    }
                }

                csvData.Rows.Add(fieldData);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }

    return csvData;
}
```

Calling with:

```
DataTable csvData = GetDataTableFromCSVFile(Filename);
```

But this doesn't seem to return anything from the file.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: [Stop Rolling Your Own CSV Parser!](http://www.secretgeek.net/csv_trouble)

Comment: isn't `int j = _dt.Rows.Count;` always =0 ?

Comment: FromCsv return a `List<Dto>` so select is a `IEnumerable<List<Dto>>`. I guess you are missing a Yield here instead of return. And return oone Dto instead of a list as a line provide by readline should contain only one Dto.

Comment: Thank you @Reniuz. Clearly I need to learn more about the available C# packages.

Comment: Consider using Nuget package CsvHelper. Declare a `CsvFile<DtoClass>` object. and Read from it. Result is the requested list. Use a derived class of `CsvClassMap<DtoClass>` to map the read columns to your properties

Comment: I recommend using [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/). you will be able to address field by index or by column very easly

Comment: Thanks guys, as always very helpful :) I will use the csvhelper package and also spend a little more time familiarizing myself with C#'s package management system.

Comment: Now that you know the best solution, `var result = File.ReadAllLines("pathTo.csv")
    .Select(a => a.Split(','))
    .Select(x => new MyObject
    {
        prop1 = x[0],
        prop2 = x[1],
        //etc..
    })
    .ToArray();` will return a Dto[]. It can be use as a quick fix the time you studies better and more robust solution.

Comment: Here is the simpliest exemple of csv helper that will match your probe with out many modification http://carlosferreira.com/reading-csv-files-using-csvhelper-package-c-ienumerable/.

Comment: can't get the csvhelper to work either... won't convert the fields for some reason.

I'm just gonna use your solution there @DragandDrop thanks again

Comment: @Reniuz Um. The code is using `TextFieldParser `... that's not a homebrewn thing; it's the native .Net CSV parser.

Comment: @Nyerguds Target of my comment was `FromCsv` method

Comment: @Medicineman25, I will always recommend CSV helper. If you have issue making it work, and you want a solid solution. May you provide an Bogus exemple of your data. 1 line for header, 1 for valid data, 1 for every format error that may exist. I know Im a bit late..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One simple way will be to split the lines and select them into your new object.

```
var result = File.ReadAllLines("pathTo.csv")
                .Select(line => line.Split(','))
                .Select(x => new MyObject { 
                    prop1 = x[0],
                    prop2 = x[1],
                    //etc.. 
                })
                .ToArray();
```

Comment: This is great, short and nice

Comment: @nights, From someone who dealed with a lot of CSV. having to enumerate prop2 and manually map them to index is bad(too hard). I advocate for CsvHelper or any CSV lib. this answer does not have `Convert.ToDouble` op needed. It loose to CSV helper in all domain. Less readable, less maintainable, etc. It only win in academics, when teacher that didn't face real life data forbid you to use real life solution.

Answer (score 1):

There's no point in recreating the wheel, Id just use [CsvHelper](https://web.archive.org/web/20180415193649/http://joshclose.github.io:80/CsvHelper/2.x), it has support for what you're doing in addition to handling malformed CSV's you can additionally set up [mapping](https://web.archive.org/web/20180415193649/http://joshclose.github.io:80/CsvHelper/2.x#mapping) like so:

```
public sealed class MyClassMap : ClassMap<MyClass>
{
    public MyClassMap()
    {
        AutoMap();
        Map( m => m.CreatedDate ).Ignore();
    }
}
```

Then you can get the object like so:

```
var csv = new CsvReader( textReader );
var records = csv.GetRecords<MyClass>();
```

Comment: I disagree, the accepted answer is practically the same thing. I don't understand why csvhelper is even a project when all they have done is add some syntactic sugar. If I wanted, I could simply wrap the accepted answer in a class and call it a day. Not to mention I couldn't get csvhelper to work with my data. No I think there is enough abstraction in C# without adding yet another unnecessary layer on top.

Comment: @Medicineman25, csvhelper has additional support for malformed classes,   You may be able to parse one class with a few lines of code but you won’t support nested classes or child classes out of the box.  Csvhelper is fluent and saying is syntactic sugar is like say automakers syntactic sugar. But it’s your project so you can do what you want it in ;)

Comment: My apologies @Johnny 5 where are my manners? ... thank you for your answer. My comment is born from the seemingly endless and rather superfluous abstraction that is native to C#

Comment: Which wheel? the project is since deleted.

Comment: @nights ,  The Documentation got a lot simplier in the [getting started](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/getting-started) article. I recommend clicking a few example on reading https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/reading and mapping to see how it roll https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/configuration/class-maps

Comment: If you have any specific question using it fell free to ask a Question on SO. and ping me on my answer. Don't forget to include a part of your CSV even with bogus data. showing the type and the possible inputs.